# Oracle Trigger manual Insert

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have an After insert or Update trigger that works correctly if I run the scripts (insert into ...) but if I update or insert a record manually directly from the data tab in sql developer the trigger does not work. it is possible to enable?
Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to show all relevant code, please.

Comment: You need to at least show us what the trigger is supposed to do, and how you know whether or not it has worked (or fired). As it will fire from the data tab, I'd guess you're using `dbms_output`and can't find the output?

Comment: yes correct, i using dbms_output

Comment: dbms_output only writes to the command-line output buffer. you can't use it to return text to a GUI application like SQL Developer unless you execute your insert as a SQL script.